# Is it possible to check if error code has been retrived using GetLastError

Tags: c++, winapi

If you have a large system that automatically shows a nice window explaining a caught exception it would be nice to be able to present the error code along with the message (for further investigation). But since some functions calls are to failing windows functions, which set an error code, and some are local failing functions that don't set the error code I wonder if there is a way to check if the last set error code has been "retrieved" already.

Let's say we have a piece of code

```
if (!CopyFile(("c:\foobar.txt", "d:\foobar.txt",FALSE))
{
  throw FooBarException("bla bla bla");
}
```

Here it would be possible to automatically add the error code to the error message since CopyFile is a function that sets the error code on failure. Now, we could add the error code "manually" within the if statement and append it to the error string passed when creating the exception. But to not have to change thousands of places in existing code we could have the constructor of the *FooBarException* automatically fetch and append the error code. But this also raises the issue in question.

What if some code that doesn't set the error code causes a *FooBarException* to be raised. Then the constructor would *GetLastError* but get an error code that might not be connected to the current exception at all.

But if the constructor of *FooBarException* could call some *LastErrorRetrived* (or something similar) and get *true* if the error code has already been retrieved before it ould ignore appending the error code and assume it's connected to an earlier error.

Now I understand this can go haywire if one does not actually "retrieve" the error code after every windows function that can fail and set the error code. But let's assume this is done.

Comment: Use two exception types, one for errors that sets the `GetLastError` code, one for errors that doesn't. If you inherit both from [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) you can override [`what`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) to return the appropriate error message.

Comment: Valid point, but that would still require you to go through the code (a couple of hundred thousand lines of code) and check each possible place where the exception in question is raised and make the determination which type should be used. The best way in many cases, but very time consuming.

Comment: "... to not have to change thousands of places in existing code ..." -- Why not? If you change the exception type(s) appropriately (even for only the refactoring) then you compiler will spit out each and every place you have to check. Better than relying on some brittle approach where you assume things have/or have not happened.

Comment: Do you want to know whether errorcode was set by the "very last win API call before the exception was raised"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetLastError() just gets thread's last-error code value and that's all. So, I believe there is no way to know was it called once or a few times. Moreover, I don't really think you need to.

The best solution here is to create *WinAPIException* class derived from some base class (for example, *std::exception* ). In constructor *WinAPIException* should call GetLastError() before any other WinAPI call. It guarantees that the error value isn't change.

```
if( !CopyFile("c:\foobar.txt", "d:\foobar.txt",FALSE) )
    throw WinAPIException("Houston, we have a WINAPI problem");
```

If you check result after non-WinAPI function call - just use other exception class (derived from the same base class):

```
if( std::cin.get() < 0 )
    throw std::runtime_error("Houston, we have runtime problem");
```

Thus, you can use single try...catch statement to catch both exceptions:

```
try {
    ...
} catch( std::exception &e ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

The value returned by [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms679360.aspx) is simply a global (per-thread) object without any logic attached. It can be accessed through `GetLastError`, [`SetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms680627.aspx) and the mysterious [`RestoreLastError`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/29/10159322.aspx).

I'm afraid I have to break the news: Retrofitting error handling into a system that wasn't prepared for it is tedious.

There is really very little you can do outside of implementing several exception classes (for Win32 error codes, COM `HRESULT`s, etc.) and changing each and every invocation.